# Sticky'd element inside a fixed element scrolls with content outside fixed element

Tags: css

I have an element with `position: sticky` nested inside an element with `position: fixed`, which is overlaid on top of the page's scrollable main content like so: https://jsfiddle.net/feihcsim/z5p6tjmb/25

Why is it that the `sticky`d element scrolls when I scroll on the main content?

Answer (score 0):

it's doing exactly what `position: sticky;` does...

sticky  The element is positioned based on the user's scroll position.

A sticky element toggles between relative and fixed, depending on the scroll position. It is positioned relative until a given offset position is met in the viewport - then it "sticks" in place (like position:fixed).

**Note:** Not supported in IE/Edge 15 or earlier. Supported in Safari from version 6.1 with a -webkit- prefix.

As you are offsetting it from the beggining you can't see the position change.

Here you can appreciate it:
https://jsfiddle.net/z5p6tjmb/39/